# Can it be said that the verbs in -ить are more localized in space and time than in -еть?

Tags: глаголы, суффиксы, окончания, спряжение

My gut feeling is this is the case.

Verbs in -еть usually have prolonged, undetermined and broad character, while verbs in -ить are more "here and now". Is this view correct?

Examples: хаметь-хамить, грубеть-грубить, чернеть-чернить, сереть-сорить, пиздеть-пиздить, глазеть-сглазить, пустеть-пустить, холодеть-холодить, тяжелеть-тяжелить, тупеть-тупить, светлеть-светить, хорошеть-хорошить, хитреть-хитрить, худеть-худить, толстеть-толстить, редеть-редить, жалеть-жалить etc.

Comment: I don't think so. But could you share some examples, please?

Comment: @Dmitry чернеть - чернить

Comment: @Dmitry пустеть-пустить, глазеть - сглазить, сереть - сорить.

Comment: @Anixx those are nice examples (also, not trying to troll, but "пиздеть" and "пиздить" also comes to mind) - I think the question will benefit if you'll add this examples right into the question.

Comment: @shabunc хаметь-хамить, грубеть-грубить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/#id-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%C2%A763) the "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник" (под редакцией Лопатина):

> Глаголы на `−еть` – непереходные 1-го спряжения – имеют значение ‘стать
>   каким нибудь, приобрести признак’, например, "обессилеть".

while

> Глаголы на `−ить` (в 1 м лице и  отсутствует) – переходные 2-го
>   спряжения – имеют значение ‘сделать каким нибудь, наделить признаком’,
>   например, "обессилить".

Moreover, "-енеть"/"-енить" cases are mentioned specifically:

> −ене(ть), – ени(ть). Приобретение какого нибудь признака, переход в
>   другое состояние выражается также в непереходных глаголах 1-го
>   спряжения на `−енеть`, в которых безударный гласный перед н 
>   передается буквой е: "леденеть", "костенеть", "деревенеть", "коченеть",
>   "травенеть", "торфенеть", "окровенеть", "остекленеть", "остервенеть",
>   "остолбенеть", "оцепенеть". Соотносительные переходные глаголы 2-го
>   спряжения на `−енить`, обозначающие наделение признаком, тоже пишутся
>   с буквой е: "леденить", "коченить", "окостенить", "окровенить", "остервенить",
>   "оцепенить" и т. п.

Why it is so and what it historical-linguistic background for this I don't know but I think it's sae to conclude that your gut feeling is right.

Comment: But there are other words not related to giving some feature. For instance, жалеть, болеть, владеть. Many of them have no pairs but they are prolonged.